# Update table from text file?

Tags: sql-server, replace, import, sql-update

I have a table T1:

| code | name |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | alias |
| 002 | row |

and I have a text file code.txt

```
oldCode;newCode
001;d4f
002;bc3
```

I need to update table t1 (replace the old code with the new code) and the table be like that:

| code | name |
| --- | --- |
| d4f | alias |
| bc3 | row |

Does anyone have the solution?

Comment: Use `OPENROWSET` and `JOIN` to that data in an `UPDATE` statement. `BULK INSERT` the text file into a staging table, and then `UPDATE` by `JOIN`ing that that table?

Comment: can you create the query for more understand I'm beginner in database and i need to solve this problem

Comment: The documentation has lots of information on all of these: [`OPENROWSET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [`BULK INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [`UPDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) ([Example with `JOIN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#l-specifying-a-table-alias-as-the-target-object))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking Larnu's method, a query would be like:

`UPDATE t SET t.code = DATA.newCode FROM T1 t JOIN OPENROWSET(BULK 'PATH_TO_FILE\code.txt', SINGLE_CLOB) AS DATA ON t.code = DATA.oldcode;`

Keep in mind SQL server should have access to the file.